# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ClassNotFoundException Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classpath, cp

i got a ClassNotFoundException with this code:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    MySQL.connect();
```

I imported the mysql-connector (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) and added it in a special folder (I named it External) and added it to the build-path. When I launch it in Eclipse it works fine for me but if I export it as jar and launch it by java -jar it does not work to me and I get the ClassNotFoundException...
Hope someone could help me :)
Mabye it has to do something with the classpath but how do I edit it because -cp External/mysql-connector.jar does not work..

Comment: eclipse doesn't export mysql connecter jar file.you can add it manually

Comment: You have to add the mysql-connector into the classpath when running your JAR with java -jar.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `java -jar` the `-cp` option is ignored. See the tool documentation. You have to list the dependent JARs in the Class-path entry of the Manifest.

However the `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007.

Comment: But if I do not use it I get a No suitable driver found exception :/

Comment: So? That just exchanges one error for another. No improvement; no worse. If you list the JAR file in the Class-path entry of the Manifest you won't. Try it before you post again.

Comment: How can I list them in the Class-Path

Comment: Oh come off it. Have you considered looking any of this up? Or do you need spoon-feeding all the way to working code?

Answer (score -1):

I also think you have to config the imported library by [-cp] like

```
java -cp ../lib/mysql-connector.jar;../lib/* ・・・
```

Comment: java -cp External/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -jar test.jar -- this does not work and java -cp ../External/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -jar test.jar does also not work..

Comment: what about:  [java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -cp test.jar;External/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar test.main]    test.main is the main method of your test.jar